# Asterisk record all calls even when transferred

Tags: recording, asterisk, pbx

I do not know how to record **ALL** calls. I am having trouble when transferring the calls. Anyways this is my configuration:

**sip.conf:**

```
[general]
  tcpenable=yes
  udpenable=yes
  ... etc

[peer1]
  secret=somePassword
  type=friend
  disallow=all
  ... etc

[peer2]
  secret=somePassword
  type=friend
  disallow=all
  ... etc

[peer3]
  secret=somePassword
  type=friend
  disallow=all
  ... etc
```

**extensions.conf**

```
...
...
exten => 101,1,NoOp(Calling peer1)
; record call
same => n,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav)
; call peer
same => n,Dial(SIP/peer1)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => 102,1,NoOp(Calling peer2)
; record call
same => n,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav)
; call peer
same => n,Dial(SIP/peer2)
same => n,Hangup()

exten => 103,1,NoOp(Calling peer3)
; record call
same => n,MixMonitor(${UNIQUEID}.wav)
; call peer
same => n,Dial(SIP/peer3)
same => n,Hangup()
```

This configuration works great most of the time. Most calls get recorded. There is a scenario when the call will not get recorded. If I perform the following steps the call will not be recorded:

1. `peer1` calls `peer2` and there is a new recording which is great.
2. `peer1` transfers the call to `peer3`
3. The moment the call is transferred, MixMonitor stops recording the call.

**How can I record all calls even if I perform this scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

You have start again mixmonitor for transfered call, using SAME file(option 'a')